# MVC5 Razor - bootstrap button class not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have been trying to add a bootstrap class to my button but it is not working and my button displays as a simple hyperlink

This is what I have currently as my button:

```
[@Html.ActionLink("Remove", "RemoveItem", new { id = item.ItemID, @class = "btn btn-warning btn-xs" },
                            new
                            {
                                data_confirmprompt = "Are you sure you want to delete this?
                            })
```

Comment: Does your rendered HTML include the `class="btn btn-warning btn-xs"` attribute on the hyperlink ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the function that you are calling within your code :

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
  this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
  string linkText,
  string actionName,
  object routeValues,
  object htmlAttributes);
```

So, this should be what you're looking for :

```
@Html.ActionLink(
  "Remove",       // The hyperlink text
  "RemoveItem",   // The controller name
  null,           // The annoymous type for route parameters
  new             // The annoymous type for HTML attributes
  {
    id = item.ItemID,
    @class = "btn btn-warning btn-xs",
    data_confirmprompt = "Are you sure you want to delete this?"
  }
)
```

This is what Chris has said in his answer and beaten me to it!

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the class attribute in the wrong anonymous object. The first anonymous object you have in the method call corresponds to the `routeValues` param, while the second is for `htmlAttributes`. Move the `@class` bit to the second object and you should be fine.